# C# LINQ GroupBy error Only one expression can be specified in the select list

Tags: c#, linq

I have Linq query I group it by 3 fields and it returns result I want to get the fields of grouped collection based on the key but when I use below query it gives me error as

"**Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."**

Below is my query

```
var patientResults = context.GetTable<PatientResult>().
              Where(r =>
                      r.MeasurementTime < filterValues.DateTo.AddDays(1).Date
                      && r.MeasurementTime >= filterValues.DateFrom
                      && devicesFilter.Contains(r.DeviceId)).
                       GroupBy(x => new { x.MeasurementTime, x.Model, x.DeviceId });


var patientResults12 =patientResults.Select(x => new PatientMeasurementResult()
                 {
                     MeasurementTime = x.Key.MeasurementTime,
                     Model = x.Key.Model,
                     DeviceId = x.Key.DeviceId,
                     PatientId = x.FirstOrDefault().PatientId,
                     PatientName = x.FirstOrDefault().PatientName
                 });
```

I want 2 elements PatientId and PatientName, and I don't want to include them in groupby
If I just give FirstOrDefault() either for PatientId or PatientName it works fine, but when I give for both it gives above error.

Comment: Why are you doing FirstOrDefault on x. Why can't you do x.Key.Patientid and x.Key.Patientname?

Comment: PatientId & PatientName are non-key element so cant use them in group by so they cant be key and cant be used as x.key.patientid, and importantly they can be null

Comment: What's the structure of your class PatientResult.

Answer (score 0):

Just call FirstOrDefault() once, like so:

```
var patientResults12 = patientResults.Select(x =>
{
    var patientMeasurementResult = new PatientMeasurementResult()
    {
        MeasurementTime = x.Key.MeasurementTime,
        Model = x.Key.Model,
        DeviceId = x.Key.DeviceId,
    };

    var result = x.FirstOrDefault();

    if (result != null)
    {
        patientMeasurementResult.PatientId = result.PatientId;
        patientMeasurementResult.PatientName = result.PatientName;
    }

    return patientMeasurementResult;
});
```